# Is it possible to pass the parameter in php execution?

Tags: php, exec

Hi I am trying to run a C binary program in a php script.
The name of the binary program is `prog` and it takes one or two parameters. In terminal this binary program runs fine with this command:

```
prog param1
```

In a php sript, I am trying to run the above command. But I am not sure if this syntax is correct. I have the following:

```
exec('../permission/prog param1', $output, $return);
```

I am not seeing expected behavior after executing the php file. Is it possible to pass the parameter like this in php?

Thanks!

Comment: That's how it is supposed to. Read up on [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) though. Be more specific about the issue or misbehaviour you're running into.

Comment: i think insted of ../permission try to give full path

Comment: How long does the program take to execute and what does it do? While executing the program, php waits for it to finish. This could make the php script exceed the max 30 second execution time, especially if the script requires user input

Comment: @Dcdanny It should take a second. All it does is generating a small file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to do couple of things and check again:

1. Your function params uses is fine but try using the full script path.
2. If still it does not function from with in your php script. You will need to check and see if the apache group:user has the ownership of running the permission/prog script or not. If not try giving the ownership to apache group:user. The apache group:user may apache:apache. You will need to exactly check for what group and user is there in your server for apache.

Answer (score 0):

PHP usually runs executables from the user and group of `www-data`

This will likely be different to the user you are using in the terminal. Check that `www-data` has permission to execute the binary